# Display datapoint value above datapoint in GraphView

Tags: android, android-graphview

I'm using GraphView for Android, and i'm trying to display the datapoint value above said datapoint in case of an onClick event. 
Currently, i'm using

`series.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, dataPoint.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });`

Is there a way of showing the value right above the datapoint ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by showing the value above the data point?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean the value of the datapoint. Meaning if i click on the datapoint its value should appear/disappear on top of it.

Comment: I don't believe the library does support such a thing at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add text on top of datapoints by using `PointsGraphSeries` with a custom shape (text):

```
PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> seriesPoints = new PointsGraphSeries<>(dataPoints);
seriesPoints.setCustomShape(new PointsGraphSeries.CustomShape() {
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, float x, float y, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(38);
        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(dataPoint.getY()), x, y, paint);
    }
});
mGraph.addSeries(seriesPoints);
```

In your case, you could remove the text after some delay with:

```
mGraph.removeSeries(seriesPoints);
```

Comment: Hi @Raphael, Can you share a screenshot? How will it look after that? AND Can this be work on LineGraph?